# Access textfield data in UIalertview globally

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring, uitextfield, uialertview

i have created an alertview with textfield and the details which is inserted in textfield have to be accessed when i select a button.here is my code

```
-(IBAction)addcart:(id)sender{

UIAlertView *customAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter Your quantity" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];

txtfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 40.0, 260.0, 20.0)];

[txtfield setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[txtfield setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];



[customAlertView addSubview:txtfield];

[customAlertView show];

[customAlertView release];   }

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

if (buttonIndex == 0)
{
    NSString* str=txtfield.text;

    qtystr=str;
}


-(IBAction)showcontent:(id)sender{

NSLog(@"%@",qtystr);    }
```

here qtystr,txtfield i've created property and synthesized it..But i dont know where i'm missing it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `qtystr` is a property, use `self.qtystr` when you reference it.

(Otherwise, use a breakpoint on `qtystr=str;` to see what the values are during the assignment.)